# Determining impedance of the circuit from peak values of current and voltage

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-circuits, electricity, electrical-resistance

Does the following equation given in my book $$i_m = \frac{V_m}{Z}$$

where $i_m$ and $V_m$ are peak values of current and total voltage $V_m = \sqrt{(V_L-V_C)^2+V_R^2}$ and $Z$ is impedance, hold for all RLC circuits? Sorry if this question is a bit simple, but it has been hard to find good sources of info on these circuits. I ask this, because a certain problem hands me all these necessary peak values, as well as the resistance and period of oscillation. I think this implies the above equation is not true.

Comment: To invite a more specific answer you need to say more about the "this" in your last sentence. But your question mustn't read as an appeal for help with homework.

Comment: I just wanted to know if the equation for peak values and impedance is true. Sorry if that was unclear.

Answer (score 1):

Your second equation holds just for all *series* RCL circuits. And we are assuming sinusoidal currents and voltages. Otherwise, not much wrong that I can see, now that you've put right the typo. Note that rms values can be used *throughout* instead of peak values if you wish.